# PHP VSW <<< (Weird Syntax with Three carets)

Tags: php, syntax

I've stumbled across some code that looks like it's alternate syntax for assigning something into a variable in PHP.

```
$VSWTags = <<<VSW
BUNCHOFHTMLANDSTUFFHERE
VSW;
```

This is in a Drupal site we have here at work, and I searched on PHP.net for the `VSW` and for the `<<<` I couldn't find anything. When I played with it in the console I saw that it basically is just support for bare words or something of that nature?

```
php > $s = <<<VSW                                                               <<< > I dont know what this is doing
<<< > but its cool
<<< > VSW;
php > print $s;
I dont know what this is doing
but its cool
php >
```

Does anyone know where the documentation is for this or what it's called?

Comment: Ah, thank you jeroen! 
The documentation for the HEREDOC is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [HEREDOC](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) - very usefull for large strings.

Comment: Thanks Nemutaisama, I have to wait 6 minutes before I can accept an answer, but I'll accept this one when I can if the question isn't removed as a duplicate.